# The keyword 'export' is reserved Eslint Angular

Tags: angular, eslint, keyword

I have an Angular application which is working good.

I am trying to upgrade the Angular version for my application and have installed Eslint to check the code before I push the latest version to production.

It is complaining about how I use the export keyword in a plain javascript library in the project.

The javascript library in question is like this:

```
export function calculateTotalCosts(assets, misc_items, shots, type) {
  .....
}
```

The exact error reads:

```
eslint(e:1), Parsing error: The keyword 'export' is reserved
```

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That doesn’t sound like an eslint error really? Can you show the complete and exact error? And does it only occur when linting?

Comment: @MikeOne it only occurs with eslint - I've added the exact error in the question above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function calculateTotalCosts(assets, misc_items, shots, type) {
  .....
}

module.exports = calculateTotalCosts;
```

you can modify the code to use a different approach for exporting the function.